# What exactly can moderators see when one raises a flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderator-tools

The flagging system has changed quite a bit since the days of flag weight, and I feel this has mostly been for the best. In particular, having detailed feedback on which flags were appropriate and which flags weren't is quite helpful for fine-tuning one's flagging behaviour. On the other hand, now that flag weight is gone, it's not clear to me whether something else has replaced it on the moderator side of things. So, to be clear, I'd like to ask

#### when one raises a flag on a post, what exactly can the responding moderators see?

Do they have access to

- the username of who raised the flag?
- their flagging statistics?
- some sort of flag weight?
- some other information?

Does this depend on the type of flag? That is, are spam/offensive/not-an-answer/very-low-quality flags different from the custom `other (needs ♦ moderator attention)` flag?

Finally, certain flags are visible to 10k users, who can confirm or dispute them as extra information for the moderators that then act on them. Can those 10k users see more information than just the type of flag?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Diamond moderators have access to a lot of information, but not all of it is displayed in the flag queue.

> the username of who raised the flag

This is displayed in the flag queue for all flags.

> their flagging statistics

Moderators can see how many flags you've raised, how many were helpful, and how many were declined by going to your profile. This is not displayed with your flag, as it generally isn't helpful. (I used to only bother to look at this if I noticed someone doing something consistently wrong, or if they'd entered into a moderator election.)

> some sort of flag weight

No, this is gone, and not replaced with anything that moderators can see. (As far as I know.)

> some other information

Most of the information moderators see when handling flags is about the flagged post itself, not the users who posted or flagged the post.  For 99% of flagged posts, they can see everything they need to see either in the moderator queue or by going to the posted question/answer itself. Information about the poster is sometimes useful, but information about the flagger almost never is.

Comment: If I flag a comment, can you ( moderator ) see me as flag riser ?

Comment: @Kedarnath No, not for comment flags. I'm not sure why we don't see that, but I don't often wonder "who is raising all of these comment flags?" so I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: Does it means that, Comments flag queue is different that other flag queue like spam flag queue etc ?

Comment: @Kedarnath No, all flags go to the same queue, but we can filter it by flag type if we want to. Comment flags are just displayed slightly differently than the others.