# What sort of UI does a moderator see when processing flags?

Tags: support, flags, moderator-tools

I've had a few flags declined from time to time that make we wonder what the UI looks like for a moderator when reviewing flags? The odd fat-finger aside I suspect a few things that throw some reviews are:

- Is it obvious that a flag was raised on a previous revision of a post?
- If multiple flags of different types are raised, for example NAA and spam is it clear that handling it as NAA will decline spam flags?

I noticed when posting this question that [What exactly can moderators see when one raises a flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226144) came up as related but I'd like to know the UI and workflow if possible. I realize moderators may not be able to describe it in detail because of the moderator agreement, but assume it's not really top-secret so if not perhaps a team member could provide a redacted version of things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it obvious that a flag was raised on a previous revision of a post?

No, and I suspect I've been a 'victim' of this now and then too.

> If multiple flags of different types are raised, for example NAA and spam is it clear that handling it as NAA will decline spam flags?

It's hard to handle multiple types of flags on the same posts in a different way. We could mark them all as helpful, and later clear the spam flags if they're not appropriate (making them 'disputed'). There is no readily visible option to decline only the spam flags and leaving the other flags unhandled; @MadScientist points out an option for this in the comments but it's not widely known among moderators.

Comment: you can handle flags individually by clicking on the flag text. It's a very well hidden UI, and I'm not sure how long it exists, but it's there.

Comment: @MadScientist I believe it's been possible to do that for about as long as the flag-handling UI has existed in its current form. At least, I've been using it regularly for quite a while.

Comment: @DavidZ Found [the meta post about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225779/151385). It's 4.5 years ago that this was implemented.